# Form not validating in Django with a URLFIELD and IMAGEFIELD

Tags: python, html, django, validation

I have been trying to set up a simple form so users can register an ad to be shown on the homepage of the website. For some reason, whatever I try to do, my form is not validating. What am I doing wrong? I have tried things like adding the enctype and sifting through numerous stackoverflow questions related to this. I would appreciate if you could help! Below is my code:

Models.py:

```
    from django.db import models


    class ad(models.Model):
        ad_link = models.URLField(max_length=2000)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to="ads/")

        def __str__(self):
            return self.ad_link
```

forms.py:

```html
    from django import forms
    from .models import ad

    class AdForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = ad
            fields = ('ad_link', 'image')
```

Views.py:

```
    def ad_registration(request):
        context= {}
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = AdForm(request.POST or None)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
            else:
                form.save()
            return render(request, "ad_registration.html", {})
        else:
            return render(request, "ad_registration.html", {})
```

HTML file with form:

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-signin" method="post" action="/ad_registration">
        {% csrf_token %}
        
        <div class="d-flex flex-column pb-3">
            <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src= "/static/logo.png" alt="Logo of our school" width=23% height=23%>
        </div>
      <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Register your ad</h1>
      
      <input type="url" name="ad_link" id="inputurl" class="form-control" placeholder="URL of your ad" required>
     
      <label for="inputimage">File of Ad:</label>

      <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="inputimage" name="image" accept="image/*" required>
      
        
        
        

      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Register</button>

    </form>
```

Comment: If you need any other pieces of code please tell me.

Comment: you are not passing the request.FILES for the images:
try this :
AdForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

Comment: Thanks @Rafi! I knew it had to be some short fix!

Comment: you welcome. i am gonna put that as an answer so you can accepted  and close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not passing the request.FILES for the images
try this :

```
AdForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```